# How to calculate a googolplex

Tags: c#, math, calculator

I was curious, a googolplex is `(10^10)^100` (**Correction**: `10^(10^100)`) And I want to calculate this. How can I accomplish this?

In `C#` using the following code:

`Console.WriteLine(Math.Pow(Math.Pow(10, 10), 100));`

Literately produced the following result:

`Infinity`

[image]

Also, is it `Math.Pow(Math.Pow(10, 10), 100)` or `Math.Pow(10, Math.Pow(10, 100))` for a googolplex?

I understand that even if something like this is possible to calculate (Which I'm sure it isn't on your everyday computer) it will most likely take an infinite amount of time to complete.

I really need to get out more...

Comment: `Math.Pow(10, Math.Pow(10, 100))` is correct.

Comment: The value is beyond the range of C#'s built in types.

Comment: Is there a language I could use? Such as C++, or even assembly (Don't say that one, please don't say assembly)

Comment: " Carl Sagan estimated that writing a googolplex in standard form (i.e., "10,000,000,000...") would be physically impossible, since doing so would require more space than is available in the known universe." [[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googolplex)]

Comment: key word there `physically`, which is not what I'm wanting to do.

Comment: Then what exactly are you trying to do? What is your desired end result?

Comment: My desired end result is to display a googolplex. (Virtually impossibly by memory constrints) Best I can hope for is a `stack overflow`

Comment: Actually a `googleplex` is `10^(10^100)`, which is _much_ bigger that the stated `(10^10)^100`. Understand also that `Pow` does not simply iterate multiplications, but uses `exp` and `log` or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To write out a googolplex it would take more surface area than we have on the earth and each zero could be the size of an atom.

Check out this [excellent article](http://www.fpx.de/fp/Fun/Googolplex/) on the size of a googolplex.

FTA:

> At today's speed, the program will run for 3.125*10^85 years.

Comment: Nice account image, Good thing I have unlimited pixels! ...memory may be a problem though...

Comment: Awesome! That's plenty of time! So how do I write it?

Comment: Use some of the tricks from https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236630 to improve stdout throughput. Then you could write the answer at ~30 GiB / s on common 2021 hardware. Or about 10^18 digits per year. https://mazzo.li/posts/fast-pipes.html manages to double that throughput, but since it is no longer writing anything it feels like cheating.

Answer (score 16):

If you just want to *display* the value, this should be correct for the length of time which you are around to validate it:

```
Console.Write("1");
while (true) {
    Console.Write("0");
}
```

Or, if you want to get more specific, we can do this without any bignum libraries.

```
Console.Write("1");
const int BIL = 1000000000;
for (int i0=0; i0<10; i0++)
 for (int i1=0; i1<BIL; i1++)
  for (int i2=0; i2<BIL; i2++)
   for (int i3=0; i3<BIL; i3++)
    for (int i4=0; i4<BIL; i4++)
     for (int i5=0; i5<BIL; i5++)
      for (int i6=0; i6<BIL; i6++)
       for (int i7=0; i7<BIL; i7++)
        for (int i8=0; i8<BIL; i8++)
         for (int i9=0; i9<BIL; i9++)
          Console.Write("0");
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal was a little bit more modest the [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.11) data type and it's API would have been an answer.

Comment: The problem with this method is that `BigInteger.Pow(value, exponent)` takes an `integer` as the exponent, which is a `googol`, too much for an `int` to handel

Comment: [Link-only answers are not good answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: I found this to be a good answer, however, not quite what I was looking for. Still waiting for the correct answer... Also, What about `Link-only comments are not good comments`?

Comment: @Oxymoron That's simply not an agreed-upon opinion, and merely a statement that you decided to `put in code format`.

Comment: The opinion isn't agreed-upon. Is it under discussion?

Comment: Yes, looks like even BigInteger will not handle it. But for a 'bit' smaller numbers you should use this guy ;)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same thought. Here was my code.

```
double googol = 1e100;
        Console.Write(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < googol; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(0);
        }
```

Comment: `1e100 > int.MaxValue` even if you swap to `double i` it would fail as `1e100 + 1f == 1e100`.